# Как сосчитать количество людей в подчинение и вывести их список MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Подскажите, необходимо сосчитать количество людей в подчинение и вывести их список. `Employees.ReportsTo` указывает на `id`, того кому этот человек подчиняется.

```
Select

Employees.LastName,

Employees.FirstName,

Region.RegionDescription,

count(case when Employees.ReportsTo=Employees.EmployeeID then 1 end) as Count_of_employees,

Subordinates = STUFF((
          SELECT ', ' + Employees.LastName
          FROM Employees
          WHERE Employees.ReportsTo = Employees.EmployeeID
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

from Employees 

left join EmployeeTerritories on 

Employees.EmployeeID=EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID

left join Territories on 

EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID=Territories.TerritoryID

left join Region on Territories.RegionID=Region.RegionID

group by Region.RegionDescription,Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName
```

Comment: А подчинённых подчинённых тоже надо вывести? тогда только рекурсией.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно соединить таблицу с самой собой, при этом указав разные алиасы для таблицы, из которой вы берете список сотрудников и для таблицы, из которой вы берете список подчиненных.

Как то так:

```
Select  empl.LastName,
        empl.FirstName,
        Region.RegionDescription,
        count(empl1.EmployeeID) as Count_of_employees,
        Subordinates = STUFF((
          SELECT ', ' + empl2.LastName
          FROM Employees empl2
          WHERE empl2.ReportsTo = empl.EmployeeID
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

from Employees empl
     left join Employees empl1
            on empl1.ReportsTo=empl.EmployeeID

left join EmployeeTerritories on 

empl.EmployeeID=EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID

left join Territories on 

EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID=Territories.TerritoryID

left join Region on Territories.RegionID=Region.RegionID

group by Region.RegionDescription,empl.EmployeeID, empl.LastName, empl.FirstName
```